# Apply Dynamic Masking on a column based on another column form the table in SnowFlake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can I create a masking policy in snowflake where the masking policy needs to be applied on column 'DATE' using another column value from the same table 'SHIFT'. like below?

```sql
create or replace masking policy DATE_MASK as (DATE TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)) returns TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) ->
  case
    when current_role() in ('ROLE_NAME') then dateadd(day, SHIFT, DATE)
    else DATE
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to other row values with a dynamic mask - but you could search for that date value with a sub-query.

As an alternative, consider using dynamic masks over variant objects:

```sql
use role sysadmin;

create or replace table test_mask_variant as
select object_construct('date', '2010-01-01', 'shift', 3)::variant date;

create or replace masking policy mask_date_shift as (val variant) returns variant -> val;
alter table test_mask_variant modify column date set masking policy mask_date_shift; 

alter masking policy mask_date_shift set body ->
case 
when current_role() in ('SYSADMIN') then object_construct('date', dateadd('day', val:shift, val:date))::variant
else object_construct()::variant
end;
```

Then:

```sql
select *
from test_mask_variant
```

Returns:

```json
{
  "date": "2010-01-04 00:00:00.000"
}
```

Which is 2010-01-01, with a shift of 3.